# Why is the size of an empty dict same as that of a non empty dict in Python?

Tags: python, memory, python-2.7, dictionary

This may be trivial, but I'm not sure I understand, I tried googling around but did not find a convincing answer.

```
>>> sys.getsizeof({})
140
>>> sys.getsizeof({'Hello':'World'})
140
>>>
>>> yet_another_dict = {}
>>> for i in xrange(5000):
        yet_another_dict[i] = i**2

>>> 
>>> sys.getsizeof(yet_another_dict)
98444
```

How do I understand this?
Why is an empty dict the same size as that of a non empty dict?

Comment: A must watch video on dicts: [The mighty dictionary](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-the-mighty-dictionary-55-3352147)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two reasons for that:

1. Dictionary only holds references to the objects, not the objects themselves, so it's size is no correlated with the size of objects it contains, but with by the number of references (items) the dictionary contains.
2. More important, dictionary preallocates memory for the references in chunks. So when you created a dictionary it already preallocates the memory for the first `n` references. When it fills up the memory it preallocates a new chunk.

You can observe that behaviour, running the next peace of code.

```
d = {}
size = sys.getsizeof(d)
print size
i = 0
j = 0
while i < 3:
    d[j] = j
    j += 1
    new_size = sys.getsizeof(d)
    if size != new_size:
        print new_size
        size = new_size
        i += 1
```

Which prints out:

```
280
1048
3352
12568
```

On my machine, but this depends on the architecture (32bit, 64bit).

Answer (score 7):

Dictionaries in CPython allocate a small amount of key space directly in the dictionary object itself (4-8 entries depending on version and compilation options). From `dictobject.h`:

```
/* PyDict_MINSIZE is the minimum size of a dictionary.  This many slots are
 * allocated directly in the dict object (in the ma_smalltable member).
 * It must be a power of 2, and at least 4.  8 allows dicts with no more
 * than 5 active entries to live in ma_smalltable (and so avoid an
 * additional malloc); instrumentation suggested this suffices for the
 * majority of dicts (consisting mostly of usually-small instance dicts and
 * usually-small dicts created to pass keyword arguments).
 */
#ifndef Py_LIMITED_API
#define PyDict_MINSIZE 8
```

---

Note that CPython also resizes the dictionary in batches to avoid frequent reallocations for growing dictionaries. From `dictobject.c`:

```
/* If we added a key, we can safely resize.  Otherwise just return!
 * If fill >= 2/3 size, adjust size.  Normally, this doubles or
 * quaduples the size, but it's also possible for the dict to shrink
 * (if ma_fill is much larger than ma_used, meaning a lot of dict
 * keys have been * deleted).
 *
 * Quadrupling the size improves average dictionary sparseness
 * (reducing collisions) at the cost of some memory and iteration
 * speed (which loops over every possible entry).  It also halves
 * the number of expensive resize operations in a growing dictionary.
 *
 * Very large dictionaries (over 50K items) use doubling instead.
 * This may help applications with severe memory constraints.
 */
if (!(mp->ma_used > n_used && mp->ma_fill*3 >= (mp->ma_mask+1)*2))
    return 0;
return dictresize(mp, (mp->ma_used > 50000 ? 2 : 4) * mp->ma_used);
```